# Matlab: Copy Excel Sheet and delete defined EXCEL Names using Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, activex, worksheet

I'm currently struggling with a tricky Matlab problem:

I would like to copy the first sheet in `a.xlsx` into `b.xlsm` and place it in front of all the sheets already existent in `b.xlsm`.
Additionally I would like to delete all links to `a.xlsx`, which are automatically created in document `b.xlsm` due to the copy process.

I first tried `BreakLink` (see below) but it did not work, because there are also some named ranges defined in the EXCEL sheet, still referring to document `a.xlsx`. And this seems to prevent the deletion of the links by the breaklink method.
So now I am looking if there is any easy way to delete all defined named ranges in EXCEL document b.xlsm by using Matlab code ?

Thanks a lot.

My current code:

```
X = actxserver('Excel.Application'); 
xls_PathName = 'C:\temp\';
XW0 = X.Workbooks.Open([xls_PathName,'a.xlsx']); 
XW2 = X.Workbooks.Open([xls_PathName,'b.xlsm']); 
XW0.Worksheets.Item(1).Name = 'Sheet';
XW0.Worksheets.Item(1).Copy(XW2.WorkSheets.Item(1),[]);

%**************************************************************
% Place some code to delete EXCEL named ranges in b.xlsm here %
%**************************************************************

astrLinks = XW2.LinkSources(1)
XW2.BreakLink(astrLinks{1},1)

XW0.Close(false)
XW2.Save
XW2.Close(false)
X.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use the Matlab functions `xlsread` and `xlswrite`? I'm not sure if you are trying to copy formulas, but I think that is possible.

Since you want to place it at the start of `b.xlsm` you will either need to use `actxserver` (see [Inserting sheets with matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/insert-a-spreadsheet-after-sheet-1.html)) or manually copy each sheet one later, using the output from `xlsinfo` to get the number of sheets.

First, create a blank first sheet in `b.xlsm` (code is untested, but taken from link above)

```
e = actxserver('Excel.Application');
xls_PathName = 'C:\temp\';
b = e.Workbooks.Open([xls_PathName,'b.xlsm']); 
eSheets = b.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets;
eSheet1 = Item(eSheets,1);
eNewSheet = Add(eSheets,eSheet1);
b.Save
b.Close(false)
e.Quit
```

You probably want the three output format of `xlsread` to get the raw data as a cell array (to avoid the text and numeric data being split). Now copy the sheet from `a.xlsx` to `b.xlsm`

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread([xls_PathName,'a.xlsx'],1);
xlswrite([xls_PathName,'b.xlsm'],raw,1);
```

Hopefully that is what you wanted, let me know if I have misunderstood

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a possible solution to my problem, as I want to copy the sheet from a.xlsx to b.xlsm "as it is". So, not only the formulas but also the whole design/format of the sheet should be copied.
As sheet a.xlsx is not every time the same, it is also not possible to insert an empty design sheet to b.xlsm and fill it via xlswrite with the most current data.